# From stocks table, find out date between two dates when stock was zero

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL table https://pasteboard.co/IfFt5rF.png which has thousands of records about product flows, quantity is negative if product was sold and positive when it was bought. `product_id` is unique identifier for each product. I want to input dates and find out for each months between that date, when it was when stock was zero.

I was thinking firstly calculating starting balance for each month just by finding out sum of past periods and then add new data row by row and if it gets zero then its a date, but that logic seems super terrible and don't even know how to handle that in SQL.

I use Microsoft SQL 2014

```
declare @Table table (general_id bigint, date datetime, product_id bigint, quantity float, 
price float, code nvarchar(max), name nvarchar(max), partnumber nvarchar(max), 
description nvarchar(max), rate float, comment nvarchar(max), currency nvarchar(max), waybill nvarchar(max))

insert into @Table (general_id, date, product_id, quantity, price, code, name, partnumber, description, rate, comment, currency, waybill)
  select 1, '2019-03-1 16:33:00', 1, 10, 100, 101010, 'test', 'testnumber', 'testdescription', 1.0, 'testcomment', 'USD', 'nobill'
  union all
  select 2, '2019-03-2 16:33:09', 1, -5, 100, 101010, 'test', 'testnumber', 'testdescription', 1.0, 'testcomment', 'USD', 'nobill'
  union all
  select 3, '2019-03-3 16:33:12', 1, -3, 100, 101010, 'test', 'testnumber', 'testdescription', 1.0, 'testcomment', 'USD', 'nobill'
  union all
  select 4, '2019-03-4 16:39:00', 1, -2, 100, 101010, 'test', 'testnumber', 'testdescription', 1.0, 'testcomment', 'USD', 'nobill'
  union all
  select 5, '2019-03-4 16:39:41', 2, 40, 100, 102020, 'test', 'testnumber', 'testdescription', 1.0, 'testcomment', 'USD', 'nobill'
  union all
  select 6, '2019-03-5 16:39:00', 2, -40, 100, 202020, 'test', 'testnumber', 'testdescription', 1.0, 'testcomment', 'USD', 'nobill'
  union all
  select 7, '2019-03-6 16:39:00', 1, 25, 100, 101010, 'test', 'testnumber', 'testdescription', 1.0, 'testcomment', 'USD', 'nobill'


SELECT DISTINCT product_id, code, name, partnumber, SUM(quantity) 
FROM @TABLE
GROUP BY product_id, code, name, partnumber 
ORDER BY product_id ASC
```

If input would be date range from 2019-03-01 to 2019-03-31 then output for the current case would be. 
product_id: 1
out_of_Stock_date: 2019-03-4
zero_stock_days: 2 because at 2019-03-6 item was bought and already in stock

product_id: 2
out_of_stock_date: 2019-03-5
zero_stock_days: 26 because it was never bought again

Comment: please show what is the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query using windowed functions available in Sql Server >2008 :)

```
SELECT [lagDate] outOfStockStart,
       [date] outOfStockEnd, 
       product_id, 
       daysOutOfStock
FROM (
    SELECT *, 
           CASE WHEN LAG(stock) OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY [date]) = 0 AND stock > 0 THEN
             DATEDIFF(day, lagDate, [date]) ELSE NULL END daysOutOfStock
    FROM (
        SELECT [date],
               LAG([date]) OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY [date]) lagDate,
               product_id,
               SUM(quantity) over (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY [date]) stock
        FROM @TABLE
    ) a
) a WHERE daysOutOfStock IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I checked what you did there, obviously had some doubts if you had correctly understood everything because that seemed strange and checked your profile, seemed like you should have understood. Finally I managed to execute everything. I still dont understand what is this BUT its WONDERFUL and also BEAUTIFUL, a little bit shy but GORGEOUS. Thank you mate. I am super grateful. feeling of the result and seeing its 100% correct, is just an amazing